# Young family members to learn genetics - Amino Labs?

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, molecular-genetics, biomedical-engineering, protein-engineering

I'm an engineer but want to learn about biology with a niece and nephew who are early teens. I saw Amino Labs (https://amino.bio/) and thought because I work a lot with my hands, doing hands on exercises would be a good way to learn. I don't like text books and don't think my niece and nephew will appreciate a text book. Has anyone used Amino Labs? Any suggestions?